# Page displays syntax error only on PHP 5.3.1 but fine on 5.2.6

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have two dev servers, one is PHP version 5.3.1 which is on my main dev machine, and the laptop that's serving as a simulated webserver has version PHP 5.2.6 on it.

The index page that's hosted with PHP 5.2.6 version will display the page correctly. The page hosted on the PHP version 5.3.1 does not.

I'm getting an error which says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Greek\index.php on line 92

I have attached the code below. (However, I have to warn you it's pretty big, and I can't find a way to simply attach the file or anything like that, so it's best that I place the whole lot in here. So sorry for that.)

I have googled around to see if something like this has happened before, but I can't seem to find anything.  And I thought I'd ask here.

But any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

```
<?php
 include_once( 'admin_dataHandler.php' );

// Lets have a handle on the data connection to the data base.
// The file must be edited so that it's pointing to the correct data base.
 $dataHandler = new DataConnection();

 session_start();   // This connects to the existing session

 $msg = "";
 if ( $_SESSION['question_id'] ){
   $question_id = $_SESSION['question_id'];
 }else{
   $question_id = 1; /* Find first question */
 }
 // Debugging only...
 //echo $question_id;
 $answer = "";
 if ( $_REQUEST['action'] ){
   // an action was requested..
   $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
   if ( $action == "answer" ){
        if ( $_REQUEST['answer'] ){
            $answer = $_REQUEST['answer'];
            if ( $dataHandler->checkGreekWordAnswer( $question_id , $answer ) ){ 
              /* Check to see if the answer was correct? */
              $question_id = $dataHandler->getNextGreekWordQuestion( $question_id ); /* Find next question */
              $answer = "";
              $msg = "correct, moving on to next question.";
              // then navigate to the next word.
            }else{
              $msg = "Incorrect. For help hit the hint button";
            }
        }
    }else if ( $action == "next" ) {
        $qid = $question_id;
        $question_id = $dataHandler->getNextGreekWordQuestion( $question_id );
        if( $question_id == null ){
            $msg = "There are no more questions in this quiz";
            // Keep the user where they're at....
            $question_id = $qid;
        }
    }else if ( $action == "back" ){

        $question_id = $dataHandler->getPreviousGreekWordQuestion( $question_id );
        //echo "Current question id is " .$question_id;
        if( $question_id == null ){
            //echo "Something's wrong here...";
            $msg = "You're at the beggining of the quiz.";
            $question_id = 1;
        }
    }else if ( $action == "hint" ){
        $msg = $dataHandler->getHint( $question_id );
        if( $msg == null ){
            $msg = "There are no hints for this question.  Sorry";
        }
    }
 } 
 $question = $dataHandler->getGreekWordQuestion( $question_id );
 $_SESSION['question_id'] = $question_id;

 /** Build the HTML page that's going to be the front end of the quiz.*/
?><html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS STUFF HERE....-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="translator.js"></script>
    <title>Welcome to the Greek Quiz</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header-block">
        <img>
        Welcome to the Biblical Greek Quiz
  </div>
<? if ( $question_id == -1 ) { ?>
<!-- this needs to be a java scripty pop up 
and this H1 section needs to be in red...-->
    <h1>You win!</h1> 
<? }else{ ?>
    <div id="quiz-section">
    <span class='question'><?php echo $question; ?></span>
    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
      <input type='text' size='20' name='answer' id='greekAnswer' onkeyup="trans(this.id)" value='<? echo $answer; ?>'></input>
      <button type='submit' name='action' value='answer'>Send</button>    
      <button type='submit' name='action' value='next'>Next</button>
      <button type='submit' name='action' value='back'>Back</button>
      <button type='submit' name='action' value='hint'>Get a hint.</button>     
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
} <--------------- THis is the } it's not expecting....
?>
<?php
  if ( $msg != "" ){ ?>
<script language='javascript'>
   alert( "<?php echo $msg; ?>" );
</script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I have pointed out the offending line toward the end of my code block.

Comment: try consider php alternative control structure http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One server probably doesn't like your [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag): `<?`. Try replacing those with `<?php`.

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing `<?php` and `<?` tags in your code. I believe the `<?` variant by default is no longer recognized by PHP 5.3.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so very much :-)  I've made a note of that.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the PHP blocks in your code are started using `<?` instead of `<?php`. `<?` can be disabled on some servers. If you change them to `<?php` it will work.